# Alternatif to CSRF in Django

Tags: php, django, firefox, axios

I run an Django app inside an iframe which is with php hosted on another server.
All works except the POST request, I got error in Firefox only:

```
Request failed with status code 403  > CSRF verification failed > CSRF cookie not set
```

Previously i had Samesite warning (*Some cookies are misusing the recommended “SameSite“ attribute*) which i solved by allowing Samesite secure in php script:

*PHP*:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly',1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies',1);
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
$cookieParams[samesite] = "None";
$cookieParams[secure] = true;
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams);
session_start();
```

Warning gone but sill cookie not passing over iframe, but present in Chrome.
So i think i could skip the cookie then send it via Axios because i use Axios to send the request:

*JS*:

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
const config =
      {
          headers: {
              'method':'POST',
              'accept': '*/*',
              'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
              withCredentials: true,
              'X-CSRFTOKEN': window.csrf_token,
              //csrfmiddlewaretoken: window.csrf_token
          }
      };
axios.post(url, datas, config).then((res) => {....
```

*Settings.py*:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://myPhpsite.com', 'myPhpsite.com']
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

After tying many things i'm thinking to disable the csrf by commenting  *'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',*.
If I do it, is it an alternatif to csrf in order to get protected like csrf provide?

Comment: This is exactly what the CSRF token is supposed to prevent: that some other site can make POST requests and thus for example add an item to the cart if the user did not want that.

Comment: Can the django-csp by Mozilla can replace it?

Comment: I hope not, otherwise that would mean that FIrefox is not very safe.

Comment: I realize the problem was not FF but the extension Privacy Possum, all works after i disable it. But still interesting to know an alternatif to CSRF in Django.